# Make random movement of the object

Tags: c++, random

I'm making a robot that will move at random, but I have a problem.

http://img199.imageshack.us/img199/2599/randommovement.jpg

Why isn't this code running? Is there something wrong with it?

```
# include <iostream.h>
# include <stdlib.h>
# include <time.h>
# include <windows.h>
# include <conio.h>

void gotoxy(int x, int y){
    COORD coord;
    coord.X = x;
    coord.Y = y;
    SetConsoleCursorPosition(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), coord);
}

void gerakA(int pointX_par, int pointY_par, int stepX_par, int stepY_par);
void gerakB(int pointX_par, int pointY_par, int stepX_par, int stepY_par);
void gerakC(int pointX_par, int pointY_par, int stepX_par, int stepY_par);
void gerakD(int pointX_par, int pointY_par, int stepX_par, int stepY_par);
void gerakE(int pointX_par, int pointY_par, int stepX_par, int stepY_par);
void gerakF(int pointX_par, int pointY_par, int stepX_par, int stepY_par);
void gerakG(int pointX_par, int pointY_par, int stepX_par, int stepY_par);
void gerakH(int pointX_par, int pointY_par, int stepX_par, int stepY_par);

int main()
{
    int stepX, stepY;
    int z;
    int pointX, pointY;
    int n;
    int random; 

    cout <<"Enter your starting point:"<<'\n';
    cout <<"x:";
    cin >> pointX;
    cout <<"y:";
    cin >> pointY;


    cout << "number of step:";
    cin >> n;

    cout <<"enter the size of step :"<<'\n';
    cout <<"x:";
    cin >> stepX;
    cout <<"y:";
    cin >> stepY;

    for (z=1; z<=n+1; z++)
    {  
     srand (time(NULL));  
     random = rand() % 8 + 1;
     switch ( random ) {
       case 1:
         gerakA(int pointX_par, int pointY_par, int stepX_par, int stepY_par);
       case 2:
         gerakB(int pointX_par, int pointY_par, int stepX_par, int stepY_par);
       case 3:
         gerakC(int pointX_par, int pointY_par, int stepX_par, int stepY_par);
       case 4:
         gerakD(int pointX_par, int pointY_par, int stepX_par, int stepY_par);
       case 5:
         gerakE(int pointX_par, int pointY_par, int stepX_par, int stepY_par);
       case 6:
         gerakF(int pointX_par, int pointY_par, int stepX_par, int stepY_par);
       case 7:
         gerakG(int pointX_par, int pointY_par, int stepX_par, int stepY_par);
       case 8:
         gerakH(int pointX_par, int pointY_par, int stepX_par, int stepY_par);
     }

   }

   getch();
}

void gerakA(int pointX_par, int pointY_par, int stepX_par, int stepY_par){
     gotoxy (pointX_par,pointY_par);
     pointX_par = pointX_par + stepX_par;
     pointY_par = pointY_par;
     cout << "0";
}

void gerakB(int pointX_par, int pointY_par, int stepX_par, int stepY_par){
     gotoxy (pointX_par,pointY_par);
     pointX_par = pointX_par + stepX_par;
     pointY_par = pointY_par - stepY_par;
     cout << "0";
}

void gerakC(int pointX_par, int pointY_par, int stepX_par, int stepY_par){
     gotoxy (pointX_par,pointY_par);
     pointX_par = pointX_par;
     pointY_par = pointY_par - stepY_par;
     cout << "0";
}

void gerakD(int pointX_par, int pointY_par, int stepX_par, int stepY_par){
     gotoxy (pointX_par,pointY_par);
     pointX_par = pointX_par - stepX_par;
     pointY_par = pointY_par - stepY_par;
     cout << "0";
}

void gerakE(int pointX_par, int pointY_par, int stepX_par, int stepY_par){
     gotoxy (pointX_par,pointY_par);
     pointX_par = pointX_par - stepX_par;
     pointY_par = pointY_par;
     cout << "0";
}

void gerakF(int pointX_par, int pointY_par, int stepX_par, int stepY_par){
     gotoxy (pointX_par,pointY_par);
     pointX_par = pointX_par - stepX_par;
     pointY_par = pointY_par + stepY_par;
     cout << "0";
}

void gerakG(int pointX_par, int pointY_par, int stepX_par, int stepY_par){
     gotoxy (pointX_par,pointY_par);
     pointX_par = pointX_par;
     pointY_par = pointY_par + stepY_par;
     cout << "0";
}

void gerakH(int pointX_par, int pointY_par, int stepX_par, int stepY_par){
     gotoxy (pointX_par,pointY_par);
     pointX_par = pointX_par + stepX_par;
     pointY_par = pointY_par + stepY_par;
     cout << "0";
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "not running"?

Comment: There are errors in your code; what does the compiler say about it?

Comment: First of all, you're not specifying any namespace, things like, `using namespace std;` But that's probably a good thing, don't use that! Prefer things like `using std::cout` or just append namespace to all your functions.

Comment: Second of all, prefer C++ headers, like `<iostream>`, `<ctime>`, and `<cstdlib>` whenever possible. I can't debug further for you since I'm on OS X and lacks `windows.h`. Read compiler messages!

Comment: Another thing is you can probably do all the `gerakX` with just one method, append another parameter `char c` to it. And just `switch...case`. You're doing it in `main` anyways, move it to `gerak()` to get a cleaner `main`.

Comment: compiler said "expected primary-expression before "int"

Comment: @user2212364 the compiler also told you what line that error occurred at.  Where in your code is that error?

Comment: this is the error alert   
 http://img13.imageshack.us/img13/1411/erroralert.jpg

Comment: sorry if i using picture to show the error line...because i'm a newbie in here... :D

Answer (score 1):

So the problem linked to the `expected primary-expression before "int"` error is because you are calling your functions incorrectly:

```
gerakA(int pointX_par, int pointY_par, int stepX_par, int stepY_par);
       ^^^       ^^^^  ^^^       ^^^^  ^^^      ^^^^  ^^^      ^^^^
```

you do not have to restate the type and you are not using the correct variable names, for the above example it should be, or at least from what I can tell:

```
gerakA(pointX, pointY, stepX, stepY);
```